# Attempting to set up Technic Solder but being forced to add index.php to end of url

Tags: iis, iis-8

Is there any way that I could make it so that instead of having to go to:
http://solder.nexusgaming.org.uk/index.php/

That I could instead just go to:
http://solder.nexusgaming.org.uk/

Any help is appreciated. I am a novice to IIS, and am using PHP 7.0 with this server. If you need a link to the web application please let me know (cannot include in original post due to link limits below 10 reputation).

Comment: Did you try adding `index.php` as a default document?

Comment: `index.php` is set as the only default document and so has the highest priority. It appears to try to do the redirect to `./dashboard/` but then 404s.